# time data 'yahoo' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d in pandas datareader, python

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I'm trying to get some data in yahoo and using pandas datareader, but I got this error:

> ['MSFT']: ValueError("time data 'yahoo' does not match format '%Y-%m-%d'")

I'm new to Python.

code

```
import pandas_datareader as data
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

yf.pdr_override()
start= datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end =datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)

df = data.DataReader('MSFT', 'yahoo', start, end)

print(df)
```

Comment: What schema does `datareader` expect? Clearly `yahoo` must be in the wrong spot

Comment: so what should i do?

Answer (score 2):

It seems you are trying to use `pandas_datareader as data`, but I would recommend you using `yfinfance` directly, by using the method `download`. This function directly fetches the historical stock data for Microsoft (MSFT) from Yahoo Finance. It should work more reliably for your purpose.

```py
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

start = datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end = datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)

# Fetch data using yfinance
msft = yf.download('MSFT', start=start, end=end)

print(msft)
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime

start= datetime.datetime(2020, 1, 1)
end =datetime.datetime(2023, 1, 1)

ticker = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
df = ticker.history(period="max", start=start, end=end)
print(df)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).